# String comparison not working with filter method

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I am trying to replace and compare the string returned by rest api JSON array but somehow it's now working. Can anyone help?

Below method returning results without filtering:

`review1data.filter(element => element.PM?element.PM.toString().replace(/\s\[.*?\]/,''):element.PM === "Name, Test")`

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would help...

Comment: Data is something similar to this `[Title:Employee, PM: "Snehal, R [IT/PFS]", Title:Employee, PM: "John, T [IT/YTS]" ]` and I want to filter based on value of PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) issue, the precedence of `===` is higher than that of `?:` so your expression is being evaluated as

```
 element.PM?element.PM.toString().replace(/\s\[.*?\]/,''):(element.PM === "Name, Test")
```

which for a non-empty `element.PM` is always true. Use parentheses to explicitly define your precedence instead:

```
(element.PM?element.PM.toString().replace(/\s\[.*?\]/,''):element.PM) === "Test, Name"
```

```js
const review1data = [ { Title:"Employee", PM: "Snehal, R [IT/PFS]" }, 
                      { Title:"Employee", PM: "John, T [IT/YTS]" } ];

console.log(review1data.filter(element => 
   (element.PM ? element.PM.toString().replace(/\s\[.*?\]/,'') : element.PM) === "Snehal, R"));
```